# Searching array for strings in array VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have declared an array containing 59 items as a string. Does anyone know how I could write a bit of code that would search another range (A:F), and highlight any cell that contained one of the items in my array yellow.

I think this might be a loop inside of another loop, but I am not sure how to construct it. Apologies for the lack of code, I hope the explanation is clear.

Thanks!

Comment: Please include your coding efforts and explain where you are stuck. You might want to loop the array and use range.Find method.

Comment: One loop through your array, then hit [Range.Find()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-find-method-excel) inside.  You may need to loop the returned range if there are multiple hits expected, but that inner loop will be a lot less painful than looping the whole range.

Comment: I'm really not sure where to begin, I have declared my array with 59 items and I am stuck, I've hit a mental wall. I'm not sure how to loop through my array and through the range A:F which contain the data I want to highlight

Comment: @JNevill, are you able to give me an example of how this might look, including if there were multiple hits?

Comment: @Gandalfrandalf I've created an answer that does this as simply as possible. One loop and then `Range.Find()` which we just highlight gray using `.Interior.ColorIndex = 15`. Obviously you can do whatever you like with that returned range.

Comment: @JNevill, thank you very much - I think it was the way I was setting my range out. Thanks for helping me and sorry about my lack of code!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Loop through the array
2. Use Range.Find() method to find matching values (it returns a range)
3. Highlight that returned range directly

---

```
Sub test()
    Dim myArray As Variant
    myArray = Array("a", "c", "d")

    Dim word As Variant        
    For Each word In myArray
        Sheet1.Range("A1:A11").Find(word).Interior.ColorIndex = 15            
    Next word
End Sub
```

After running this:

[image]

This is far superior than looping the entire range inside your array loop (or your looping your array loop inside your entire range loop) since the `Range.Find()` method returns ONLY matches. Then we jsut highlight that range.

Comment: I learned something new from this answer.  Essentially, you're looping through the array once and using `find` at each step.  Does this work for non-continuous ranges?

Comment: I get an object variable/ with variable not set at this line: Range("e2:o60").Find(word).Interior.ColorIndex = 15 - do oyu know why that is?

Comment: It works against anything you can pack into a `Range` object. So I would assume that a `Range` with multiple `Areas` would work just fine here. `Range.Find()` is crazy fast and very powerful and can often take the place of a very very expensive loop. It's a handy method to keep in the back pocket.

Comment: @Gandalfrandalf That looks fine to me. Is `word` being set in the `For Each` loop? Did you qualify your `Range("E2:O60")` with the worksheet (so it's pointing at the right one instead of defaulting to the `ActiveSheet` like:: `Sheet1.Range("E2:O60")...`?

Comment: @JNevill, I think it was the way I was constructing my arrays. Thank you very much for taking the time to help me with that!

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

```
For i = BeginningOfRange to EndOfRange
    For j = LBound(Array) to UBound(Array)
        If Cells(i, ReferenceColumn) = Array(j) Then
            Cells(i, ReferenceColumn).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
        End If
    Next j
Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a rough vba code that does that... Modify it to suit your needs

```
Sub highlightcells()

    Dim arr(100) As Integer

    For i = 0 To 58
        arr(i) = i
    Next i

    Dim myrng As Range, cell As Range
    Set myrng = Range("A1:B10")

    For Each cell In myrng
        For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
            If cell.Value > 0 And cell.Value = arr(i) Then cell.Interior.Color = vbYellow
        Next i
    Next

End Sub
```